# Retrieving values from a string in scala

Tags: scala, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-junit

I am working on scala application where I  am writing automation test case using bdd cucumber. I have the following code to fetch data from URL.

```
 val url = "http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php?ip=12.215.42.19"
  val result = scala.io.Source.fromURL(url).mkString
  println(result)
```

This gives me the following output

```
{"options": [], "status": "up", "Time": "3:30"}
```

As this is the string, I want to retrieve the value of the status parameter(i.e up) as it can change at runtime dynamically. I thought of doing it using split or something but didn't get how to get the value of status in a variable. How can I get status value in a varaible?

Answer (score 2):

Can be done with a regex pattern.

```
val result = """{"options": [], "status": "up", "Time": "3:30"}"""

val statPttrn = """"status": "([^"]+)"""".r.unanchored

val status = result match {
  case statPttrn(s) => s
  case _ => "unknown"
}
//status: String = up
```

---

Regular Expression pattern explained:

- `"""` - this pattern will have the quote character `"` in it
- `"status": "` - pattern begins with these 11 characters
- `([^"]+)` - capture everything that isn't a quote `"`
- `"` - there must be a quote after the capture
- `"""` - end of pattern
- `.r` - compile as a regex (regular expression)
- `.unanchored` - the pattern might appear anywhere in the test string
- `result match {}` - test the string in the `result` variable
- `case statPttrn(s)` - if the regex pattern was found somewhere in the test string then put the captured part in variable `s`
- `=> s` - return the captured string
- `case _ => "unknown"` - the regex pattern was not found, return a default string value

Comment: @Admin it's pattern matching on regex - the regex starts capturing after `"status": "` and stops capturing when it hits a `"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that it'll return valid JSON, you're better off using a JSON parsing library than regex. For example, here's one way to read JSON with Play JSON:

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._

val url = "http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php?ip=12.215.42.19"
val result = scala.io.Source.fromURL(url).mkString
val json = Json.parse(result)
```

[Here's a Scastie example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/nNJaIjLAQRSmX8ZrNKxwsQ) (note: it isn't safe as it uses `.get` instead of `.getOrElse`)

Even better, at this point you can use Play JSON to store all fields inside a class for easier access, like this:

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._

case class MyClass(myField: String, myField2: Int)
object MyClass {
  // out of the box conversion between JSON and model
  implicit val format: OFormat[MyClass] = Json.format[MyClass]
}


val result = """{"myField": "beans", "myField2": 123}"""

val model = Json.parse(result).as[MyClass] // .asOpt is safer, puts class inside Option

model.myField // beans
model.myField2 // 123
```

[A Scastie for this one too](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/YnN8RB0gRJCE5K48NFC4DA)

Note that to use Play JSON you either need to be inside a Play project or include the following dependency in your build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.9.0"
)
```

Comment: Is htis play json lib has anything to do  with play framework?

Comment: @Admin yes, though it can be used independently of it (ie you can include the play-json dependency without needing a Play project if you want to).

Comment: Hi James. How can I achieve same using spray json ?

Comment: @Admin I don't know, I'm not familiar with spray json.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using scala 2.13, you can also pattern match directly on string:

```
val json = """{"options": [], "status": "up", "Time": "3:30"}"""

val status = json match {
  case s"""{"options": [$_], "status": "$status", "Time": "$_"}""" => Some(status)
  case _ => None
}

println(status) //Some(up)
```

`$_` matches any value and then discards it. It's used here, so the pattern matching will also work if `Time` or `options` are different than used in your example.

Comment: I am using 2.12.11. is it possible  to do this in this version

Comment: Not really, it was introduced with scala 2.13. Maybe you could check if [kaleidoscope](https://github.com/propensive/kaleidoscope) allows you to do something similar but I haven't used that library.

Comment: I am new to scala  . Could  you please tell how same thing can be achieved using kaleidscope

Comment: Kaleidoscope uses macros to inline regex in pattern matching, so it would look similarily to anwser by jwvh.